# Handling two step authentication using Python requests module

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests

My requirement is to capture cookie from authentication server and i'm able to achieve it using requests module. However, this piece of code breaks (doesn't return any cookies) when "two step verification" is enabled. Basically if i enable two-step-verification, it will send secure code to registered devices which can be used as second level of authentication. Appreciate any pointers.

```
    import requests

    auth = 'https://auth.corp.xyz.com/authenticate'

    params = {"accoundId": "xyz",
                 "accountPassword": "abc",
                 "appIdKey": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
                }

    s = requests.session()
    r = s.post(auth,params = params)


    print r.request.headers['Cookie']
    'd01_ac=9eba0c6ec6f1c09bafb29be785ad9d2373d588d3b1633a418ab932166ea5f832ae036a4f2a89a675adc6e31ebdc7c251215a4a354a085865f6c775fb4cd7544d4c64a429f27fce08bc99058d40497202a4abeedb51f73a53f246fe148560GZVX; dslang=US-EN; myacinfo=DAWTKNV2eed01036859507613988fcc6e5540e93e248a4cbee7243868b1bf5f53b3d698002b4823e872d35c848af2be146529062c6ee05e320367fadfe0e5ae507dd3c07baab03e878c12949efbeb9471111e2b0930c38c05a714f3cd8896c8b63a1201468909a0de019534f1652d49f7e7f280a82627920dbdc8a1ea413f570d16b87c063963712d5932d61a658ff380407f96f34c90e58c223d39ca90f11cc76ca521a3babf4c9f21ea0d35b77ece1b0b175ec21bd74d2d9b108759c38b71d285dde24d21c9d2eac3dfe2e4bd01df6968ebc12fe6bf132d80a0232d6b8ee61a7bfe134b86f6662316431313062326531613231MVRYV2'
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea of 2 step authentication is next:

1. You app says to the server. I want to authenticate a user. Give me a
   token.
2. Here is a token. Redirect your user to this `url` and pass a `token`
   with it.
3. Users logs in on the server
4. Server redirects user to your site by providing data about user and
   a 'token' you gave so you can match the token with an exact user who
   wanted to authenticate.

Does it make sense?

Comment: Apologies if i didn't make my question clear. I understand what is two step authentication. My question is how to get cookies when two step authentication is enabled for authentication server.